Calculating time too long for $A\succeq I$, minimize $tr(A)$ when $A$ is of dimension 4
Suppose $A_0$ is a 4*4 matrix, the constraint is $A_0\succeq I$, which means $A_0-I$ is semidefinite positive. The target function is maximum of 1-tr($A_0$), and the answer is -3 when $A_0=I$. However, when I execute the following program, it keeps running without output.
A0 = Array[a0, {4, 4}];
constraints = {VectorGreaterEqual[{A0, 
     IdentityMatrix[4]}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 4}]};
objective = 1 - Tr[A0];
maximizeResult = 
    Maximize[{objective, constraints}, Flatten[{A0}]];
maximizeResult

I tried the case for $A_0$ is of dimension 2, and it gives an answer quickly.
A0 = Array[a0, {2, 2}];
constraints = {VectorGreaterEqual[{A0, 
     IdentityMatrix[2]}, {"SemidefiniteCone", 2}]};
objective = 1 - Tr[A0];
maximizeResult = 
    Maximize[{objective, constraints}, Flatten[{A0}]];
maximizeResult

So what is the problem when calculating the dimension-4 case?

Did you try maximizeResult =    NMaximize[{objective, constraints}, Flatten[{A0}],     WorkingPrecision -> 50, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]//Chop; instead of?

@user64494 It does work.
